# Is there a word or a special phrase in English to describe the curvy upper lip that some people like Rio Ferdinand have?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, noun-phrases

I don't think many have people have that kind of upper lip (probably 10% of the population). To me personally, that kind of upper lip definitely makes a person more attractive regardless of gender. For example, Angelina Jolie's upper lip is also a little curvy although I believe people recognise the thickness of her lips more.

My point is that having a curvy upper lip is a outstanding facial feature and so people must have given it some name. What is it?

**Intended usage:**
I want to give compliment to person: "It's wonderful that you have the ... lip"

I remember watching Peter Pan on Vietnamese television when I was a kid and Wendy Darling's curvy upper lip were described with a very beautiful (and rare) phrase (in Vietnamese). Unfortunately, searching along that line didn't get me anywhere.

Below is Rio Ferdinand's super curvy lip (I count 5 curves there) vs. a Cupid's bow lip which has 3 curves (most people including myself would have this, as I have observed):

[image: 5-curve-lip vs cupid's bow lip]

And this is Rio's original lip without any of my drawing:
[image: Rio's super curvy upper lip]

Comment: I've never heard of this before.  I am probably not watching Jolie's lips very much.  And who is Rio Ferdinand anyway?

Comment: Can you add a picture to your question so we can see what you mean?

Comment: Hi @Cyberherbalist, [Rio Ferdinand](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rio_Ferdinand) is a popular footballer currently playing for Manchester United and England team :)

Comment: @KristinaLopez, sure, it seems very difficult to describe this (I've never been good at describing things anyway :D)

Comment: Oh yeah! Rio Ferdinand totally has a "kissy lip"! Lol! You did just fine, Fuzzybee.

Comment: Well, OK, @KristinaLopez, while I can understand your perspective, I don't share it! LOL.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist, actually, my idea was that the little bump at the bottom of the top lip is what I call a "kissy lip" but I see fuzzybee is referring to the curvy top part.

Comment: @fuzzybee could you re-upload R.Ferdinand's photo without the red squiggly bits? (I know, Google images exists and I did Google him before today but I think the line hides his lips!).

Comment: Done, please check @Mari-LouA

Comment: That looks much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a *technical* name to describe R. Ferdinand's shaped lips. As you pointed out that they are quite rare, and unless one day they become a medical condition (how likely is that going to happen?) or a new trend for that particular upper lip reshaping constraining plastic surgeons to agree on a name, then there's probably no need to classify them differently from a Cupid's bow mouth.

One way round you could overcome this obstacle is inventing a new name yourself, if it's any good the listener will know exactly what you mean. I thought up a few just for fun:

- a Rio pout
- lips alla Joile
- enhanced curvy lips
- kissiest lips
- bouncy lips (think bouncy/cascade slide in a funfair.)
- roller-coaster lips

If you prefer a more anatomically faithful description then use any of the words below.

[image: anatomy of lips]

Comment: Millions of thanks @Mari-Lou A! I'll call it roller-coaster lips from now on :D (gosh, how lovely that name is)

Comment: @fuzzybee  Glad to be of help. I love your enthusiasm! :D

Comment: Note that "vermilion border" is misspelled on the graphic you included. (It's one L. It's commonly misspelled. It does make the graphic less credible, unfortunately.)

Answer (score 8):

The technical term is a *tubercle*, though given the other meanings of that word it's not very poetic.

A more aesthetically pleasing term is [Cupid's Bow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupid%27s_bow).

Comment: Also known colloquially as a "kissy lip". :-{|)

Comment: Sorry, I think I led you to misunderstand the idea year, have a look at the picture I've just added ;)

Comment: Note that [Cupid's bow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Cupido4b.jpg) has exactly the shape you're describing here.

Answer (score 3):

The term for the border between the skin and the lips is [*the vermilion border*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vermilion_border). (Note the spelling; it's one l.) There is a vermilion border of the upper lip and the lower lip.

> The vermilion border is the normally sharp demarcation between the lip (red colored) and the adjacent normal skin.

I don't know what a plastic surgeon might call the extra curves (beyond the Cupid's bow) on a lip like the one you pictured. Maybe an *undulating vermilion border*?

Comment: Thanks, @JLG. However, I'm interested in the lips or the upper lip, not the border between the skin and the lip. The only reason I drew that red line was to emphasise how curvy the person's upper lip is, the same reason why people drew the red line [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cupid%27s_bow). Hope I have made myself clearer here :)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that the footballer has a **pronounced** or **prominent** cupid's bow.

Also known on the internet as **duck face**.

[image]